# R Flex Dashboard (Shiny): Dynamic behavior between checkboxgroupinput and selectinput. Prevent selectInput to go back to default values

Tags: r, shinydashboard, flexdashboard

When I check the check boxes, drop down appears with a default value selected. I change selection in drop down and when I uncheck the check box, the value in the drop down goes back to default. I want to retain the values in the dropdown. Here is my reproducible code:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------



```{r}
cars <- mtcars

checkboxGroupInput("rowfilters", "Select row filters:",
               c("Cylinder" = "cyl",
                 "Gear" = "gear"))

renderUI({
  if("cyl" %in% input$rowfilters){
    selectInput('CYL', label = "Select Cylinder:",
            choices = as.character(unique(cars$cyl)), multiple = TRUE, 
selected = "6")
  }
})  


renderUI({

  if("gear" %in% input$rowfilters){
    selectInput('GEAR', label = "Select Gear:",
            choices = as.character(unique(cars$gear)), multiple = TRUE, 
selected = "4")
  }

})

```
````

Here when I check "Cylinder" and "Gear", two dropdowns "Select Cylinder", and "Select Gear" appear with a default values. I now change the value in "Select Cylinder:" to 6,4 and 8. Now when I uncheck "Gear", the dropdown "Select Gear" disappears, which is what I want. However, the value in "Select Cylinder" goes back to default value "6". I want "Select Cylinder" to retain my previous selection 6,4, and 8.

Please let me know if you have any suggestions? Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

## Problem

The reason why your code works this way is that your `renderUI` depends on the `checkboxGroupInput`, so whenever you tick the checkboxes your app is actually rerendering the `selectInput`-s with the default values.

## Suggestion

My suggestion would be to render all the inputs, but hide the `selectInput`-s initially. Upon using the `checkboxGroupInput`, you can then toggle the visibilty of the elements.

This way they don't get rerendered and thus their values will stay the same.

## Solution

We are going to use the `shinyjs` package as it allows us to `hide`/`show` elements, etc.

1. Include `useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)`

In order to use `shinyjs` with `flexdashboard` you need to include the `useShinyjs` function in the `R chunk`.

2. Render the two `selectInput`

We will render the `selectInput` on init, but hide them with the `hidden` function from `shinyjs`.

```
hidden(selectInput(
  "CYL", label = "Select Cylinder:",
  choices = as.character(unique(cars$cyl)), multiple = TRUE,
  selected = "6"
))

hidden(selectInput(
  "GEAR", label = "Select Gear:",
  choices = as.character(unique(cars$gear)), multiple = TRUE,
  selected = "4"
))
```

3. Add `observers` for toggling visibilty.

We can toggle visibility on and off for the `selectInput` based on the value of the `checkboxGroupInput`.

```
observe( {
  if("cyl" %in% input$rowfilters) {
    shinyjs::show("CYL")
  } else {
    shinyjs::hide("CYL")
  }
})

observe( {
  if("gear" %in% input$rowfilters) {
    shinyjs::show("GEAR")
  } else {
    shinyjs::hide("GEAR")
  }
})
```

## Complete code

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyjs)
```

Column {.sidebar}
-----------------------------------------------------------------------

```{r}
useShinyjs(rmd = TRUE)

observe( {
  if("cyl" %in% input$rowfilters) {
    shinyjs::show("CYL")
  } else {
    shinyjs::hide("CYL")
  }
})

observe( {
  if("gear" %in% input$rowfilters) {
    shinyjs::show("GEAR")
  } else {
    shinyjs::hide("GEAR")
  }
})


cars <- mtcars

checkboxGroupInput(
  "rowfilters", "Select row filters:",
  c(
    "Cylinder" = "cyl",
    "Gear" = "gear"
  )
)


hidden(selectInput(
  "CYL", label = "Select Cylinder:",
  choices = as.character(unique(cars$cyl)), multiple = TRUE,
  selected = "6"
))



hidden(selectInput(
  "GEAR", label = "Select Gear:",
  choices = as.character(unique(cars$gear)), multiple = TRUE,
  selected = "4"
))
```
````